Nextjs build issue
This is package.json file
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.12.1",
    "next": "14.2.2",
    "next-themes": "^0.3.0",
    "prisma": "^5.12.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "sharp": "^0.33.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.2.2",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.5.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}

After running npm run build getting this error
PS R:\Projects\new-portfolio> npm run build

> portfolio@0.1.0 build
> next build

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.2
  - Environments: .env

   Creating an optimized production build ...
glob error [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\Ravi\Application Data'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Ravi\\Application Data'
}
Failed to compile.

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\Ravi\Application Data'


> Build failed because of webpack errors

It should create .next folder in cwd.

Try one of these:

In your schema.prisma set output = "../node_modules/.prisma/client" or remove output to make it default.
Move your project to main drive (C:)
Set outputFileTracing: false in your nextjs config file.

Source:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40760#issuecomment-2119000342
